# Create Table based on SELECT Statement Results

Tags: sql

I'm new to this site and to SQL in general. I'm hoping you might be able to help. I've created the following SQL query. I'd like to now create a new table and transfer the query results into this new table.

Is it possible to add syntax to the following query to create a table automatically?

---

```
SELECT
    Value [Value],
        DateTime [DateTime], 
            DatePart (Week, DateTime) [WeekNumber],
                hs.StorageItemID [StorageItemId]

FROM History_StorageItem hs

    JOIN History_Float hf ON hs.StorageItemId = hf.StorageItemId

GROUP BY DatePart (Week,DateTime), hs.StorageItemId, Value
ORDER BY hs.StorageItemId DESC
```

---

Also, the results of this query relating to DateTime is returning yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss...... Is it possible to drop the time from the resulting values that my query and data being added to my table is just "Date".

I really appreciate your support as my limited knowledge of SQL has only managed to take me so far.

Thanks.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? MS SQL Server, MySQL, etc?

Comment: The SQL standard  would be `create table foo as select ...`

Answer (score 1):

Answers may vary by RDBMS. You can use `INTO` to create a table from `SELECT` results, and you can cast the `DATETIME` as `DATE`:

```
SELECT
    Value [Value],
        CAST (DateTime AS DATE) [DateTime], 
            DatePart (Week, DateTime) [WeekNumber],
                hs.StorageItemID [StorageItemId]
INTO newTable
FROM History_StorageItem hs

    JOIN History_Float hf ON hs.StorageItemId = hf.StorageItemId

GROUP BY DatePart (Week,DateTime), hs.StorageItemId, Value
ORDER BY hs.StorageItemId DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

sure you can just  `INTO` clause to the select right before the FROM

```
SELECT Value [Value], DateTime [DateTime], DatePart (Week, DateTime) [WeekNumber], hs.StorageItemID [StorageItemId]
INTO [TABLENAME]
FROM History_StorageItem hs

JOIN History_Float hf ON hs.StorageItemId = hf.StorageItemId
GROUP BY DatePart (Week,DateTime), hs.StorageItemId, Value ORDER BY hs.StorageItemId DESC
```

I recommend you these tutorials

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
create table YOURTABLENAME AS
SELECT
    Value [Value],
        DateTime [DateTime], 
            DatePart (Week, DateTime) [WeekNumber],
                hs.StorageItemID [StorageItemId]

FROM History_StorageItem hs

    JOIN History_Float hf ON hs.StorageItemId = hf.StorageItemId

GROUP BY DatePart (Week,DateTime), hs.StorageItemId, Value
ORDER BY hs.StorageItemId DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, if you wanted to create a view instead of a table, you could do something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [newView] AS
SELECT
Value [Value],
    DateTime [DateTime], 
        DatePart (Week, DateTime) [WeekNumber],
            hs.StorageItemID [StorageItemId]
FROM History_StorageItem hs
JOIN History_Float hf ON hs.StorageItemId = hf.StorageItemId
GROUP BY DatePart (Week,DateTime), hs.StorageItemId, Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the date formatting methods, these change depending on your sql server type

[Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-formatting.html)

[MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

[Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_commands_1029.htm)